# Program Access Denied Error with firewall allowance on a mapped Drive

Tags: windows, firewall, nas

### I'm using a Daw(Native Instruments)

I want to offload the large library files to my NAS (TrueNAS core).
I have access to the NAS via a mapped drive [NAS Access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3vVb.png).

When I browse to the directory I'm trying to give access to Native Access (library directory Provisioning software) it throws this Access Denied Error. [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wv71W.png).

[Proof The Program Has access Past The Firewall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rm5F6.png)

I already manually allowed this program through the Defender firewall. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The issue is Windows 10+. If you run into this issue look into using iSCSI, which is better for programs accessing the NAS because the program sees a virtual drive. No authentication is required